# Refer to package name by command

Tags: macros, package-writing

Is there a possibility to refer to the package name. i.e.

```
\ProvidesPackage{SomePackage}

\def\printPackageName{\name}
```

where `\name` should resolve to `SomePackage`.

Comment: Why not the other way around? What's a possible application?

Comment: @egreg I want to create relative paths and store them in a def named as the package. The available packages for this purpose did not satisfy me (recorder mode necessary and other issues).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can evaluate `\@currname` and store it expanded into a macro, but you would be able to use the macro `\printPackageName` outside of the package usefully only once, since each other package would overwrite this macro if it would define `\printPackageName` too.

Within the package, `\@currname` stays 'alive' of course.

```
\ProvidesPackage{SomePackage}


\edef\printPackageName{\@currname}

\endinput
```

A better strategy:

```
\def\mypackagename{SomePackage}

\ProvidesPackage{\mypackagename}
```

Comment: The MWE is just for proof of concept. I intended to use this for a csname. This way, it would stay alive as well. But very nice strategy btw.